# Getting error unexpected use of history when trying to redirect?

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to build a login authentication system in where when the user introduces all of his details with the passport authentication module, the user gets redirected to the home page with the `history` module. But after doing it, it gives mme an error of usage with unexpected use of `history` when I've looked over some other solutions in stackoverflow and they all seem to make it work this way.

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import './login.css'
import axios from 'axios'
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";


function Login() {
    const [username, setUsername] = useState("")
    const [password, setPassword] = useState("")
    const [data, setData] = useState(null)

    const onChangeUsername = (e) => {
      setUsername(e.target.value)
    }

    const onChangePassword = (e) => {
      setPassword(e.target.value)
    }

    const onSubmit = (e) => {
      e.preventDefault()

      const users = {
        username: username,
        password: password
      }
      axios.post('http://localhost:4000/users/login', users)
      .then(res => console.log(res.data))
    }

    const loginUser = () => {
      axios.get("http://localhost:4000/users/user", {
        withCredentials: true
      }).then(res => {
        setData(res)
        if(res.status === 200) return history.push("/home")
      })
    }
    console.log(data)

    return (
        <div>
          <img src="https://www.freepnglogos.com/uploads/twitter-logo-png/twitter-logo-vector-png-clipart-1.png" className="twitterlogo____image"/>
          <h1 className="login_____headertext">Log in to Twitter</h1>
          <div className="placeholder_____global">
          <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
            <input className="placeholder____div" placeholder="Phone, email or username" onChange={onChangeUsername}/>
            <div>
              <input className="placeholder____div" placeholder="Password" type="password" onChange={onChangePassword}/>
            </div>
            <div>
              <button className="twitter___loginbuttonpage" onClick={loginUser}>Log in</button>
            </div>
            </form>
            <div className="forgetPassword_____div">
              <p>Forgot password?</p>
              <p>·</p>
              <p>Sign up for Twitter</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Login
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks like you're importing useHistory hook but not initializing it.

Add the following below your component state:

```
const history = useHistory()
```

Comment: I guess this is deprecated though. You can use navigate instead of useHistory. import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom' and you can continue like the same way. const navigate = useNavigate(). and just navigate("your/page")